# Footers affecting webpage and not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css

Since I added footers to the webpage I got a scroll bar at the bottom leading to a white rest of the page, and the 2 footers don't seem to fit correctly above each other: [Webpage Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSurE.png)

```
<div>
        <p id="Footer" style="color: #ADD8E6; background-color: red; font-size: 28px; text-align: center; position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%;">
            Delicious no-frill meals, all custom-selected for your specific calorie goal, delivered to your inbox weekly.
        </p>
        <p id="Copyright" style="color: #000000; background-color: white; text-align: center; position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%;">
            © 2021 Souheil Tawil
        </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you erase `position:abolute; bottom:0;` ? It would be good if you could share all the code.

Comment: I believe that jumps it to the top. but yeah it's hard without seeing the whole thing

Comment: Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/AjhJWhr8
If I remove position:abolute; bottom:0; it would throw the footer back to the center.